# WSL2: Issue installing new kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I will preface this by saying: I don't have a lot of experience in a Linux environment.

I am trying to install ROCm on WSL2 running Ubuntu. I will be using PyTorch for a class and I want to use my GPU for compute. ROCm installed fine, however, I kept getting the error `ROCk module is NOT loaded, possibly no GPU devices`.

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377660/wls-rocm-install-problems-possibly-no-gpu-devices) post which indicated that the problem could be that WSL doesn't allow you to install modules. That linked to a comment found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645131) which showed how to install a new kernel. I followed the instructions, but I have run across an error when running `make`.

The error is:
`No rule to make target '/home/<USER>/lkm_example.o', needed by '/home/<USER>/lkm_example.mod'.  Stop.`

(`<USER>` is my username, I just didn't want it out here)

Through Google, I found several posts saying that I need to install `linux-headers`. I tried running `sudo apt-get install kernel-headers`, but that resulted in an error: `E: Unable to locate package kernel-headers`

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

> I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1377732/1165986) which indicated that the problem could be that WSL doesn't allow you to install modules.

Hey, that's my answer!  Keep in mind:

- I prefaced it with:

  > *"While I don't have any AMD GPU systems with which to try this out (nor do I know for sure if ROCm works on WSL2) ..."*.
- And it has no upvotes, is not accepted, nor does it have any comments letting us know one way or the other whether it helped.

So ... don't trust it as being anywhere near reliable!  Feel free to downvote it even!  It's tough to say that about my own answer, but in retrospect it probably *wasn't* accurate.  I'll add a link from it to *this answer*, however, so that it redirects to the latest info.  Whether the info below is now *correct* or not, I'll need you to help me with!

> I will be using PyTorch for a class and I want to use my GPU for compute.

Okay, *that's* the question I'm going to address, rather than how to build the kernel with ROCm support (since I no longer think that will help).

At this point, I still don't have an AMD GPU to be able to test this out on directly, but I have done some GPU compute work on my nVideo 2070 under WSL2 now, at least.

So here's my *latest* thinking, looking at that past question, your question, and some other information:

- ROCm likely isn't needed under WSL2.  WSL2 makes the GPU available to Linux through a passthrough system using the *Windows* (not Linux) driver.  If you look under `/usr/lib/wsl`, you'll find two directories which are mounted into your WSL2 instance -- `../drivers` and `../lib`.  They are added to the library cache by the (also injected in), `/etc/ld.so.conf/ld.wsl.conf`.

  It's *these* libraries and drivers which give you access to the GPU.
- When I looked at the other question last year, I didn't realize that ROCm was the *Linux* equivalent library for GPU compute.  And if it does install as a module, then it's not likely to be useful under WSL2 anyway, as it won't have the direct access to the GPU that it needs.  In retrospect, I should have been able to figure that out with what I knew then.

So what *do* you need to use Pytorch under WSL2 on your AMD GPU?  Again, taking a guess here, but ...

- [This doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-pytorch-wsl) seems to indicate that you need Windows 11.  While I thought that most of the GPU compute support was available in Windows 10, this may be one area that requires Windows 11.  You don't mention your Windows version, so I'm not sure if this will be possible for you or not.
- The latest AMD drivers for *Windows*.  Most anything in the last year or so should be sufficient.
- An appropriate Python environment.  Microsoft [recommends Conda](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-pytorch-wsl).  I ended up using Docker myself for TensorFlow, at least.
- Dependencies are `libblas3 libomp5 liblapack3`
- And then `pip install pytorch-directml`

Honestly, that should be about it.  According to [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-accelerated-training?source=recommendations#pytorch-with-directml), AMD is supported for PyTorch with DirectML.

When running TensorFlow on my nVidia under WSL2, I didn't require *any* additional native drivers/modules.  I *did* have to provide the `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` directory to Docker, but that's only because I needed to run a specific older Python version for TensorFlow, and the easiest way to do that was via Docker.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm on Windows 10 21H2. I will try installing `directml` and see if that works. Out of curiosity, what is the reason for running in a virtual env like with conda, instead of just the general python environment?

Comment: It looks like DirectML on Windows works in Win10, while the WSL version is only on Win11.

Comment: @Excelsior That's a good point - Even if you can't run it in WSL2, you can still run the Windows version on Win10.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the PyTorch with DirectML page and installed it. However, it still doesn't recognize my GPU. As such, it defaults to the CPU and runs MUCH slower than using the CPU through WSL. I tested multiplying 2 tensors together on the cpu; WSL: 10 sec; DirectML: 6 min 26 sec.

Comment: @Excelsior Apologies for not getting back to you.  I kept reading the comments on this one way too late at night, and then forgot to come back to it the following morning(s)!  So the difference in CPU calc times between WSL and Windows is definitely odd.  Did you ever make any sense of that?  I think since we're into the "Windows" territory, more than Linux, it's probably better to post a new question on Stack Overflow.  I definitely haven't done anything with DirectML or Pytorch on the Windows side, but if link it here (if you repost), I'd be interested in following any progress.  Thanks!

Comment: I just tested pure PyTorch on Windows and it actually performed a little better than on WSL. I think the earlier issue may have been with either conda or the DirectML backend/framework